# Unable to convert back changed date time to timeStamp in python

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I want to convert  `timestamps` to `dates` and truncate `minute` and `seconds`,then, convert it back to `timestamps`. I know I can do that with some mathematical algorithm like  `timestamps/60` or `timestamps/3600`, but I want to use `Python` provided functions. My code is like below. I tried two methods:

```
for timeStamp in lineTimeStamps:
    #first try 
    day1=datetime.datetime.\
        fromtimestamp(float(timeStamp)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")
    timestamp1 = time.mktime(day1)
    #second try 
    day2=datetime.datetime.\
        fromtimestamp(float(timeStamp)).\
        replace( minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).timetuple()
    timestamp2 = time.mktime(day2)
```

In `timestamp1 = time.mktime(day1)`, I got the error like:

> TypeError: Tuple or struct_time argument required

In `timestamp2 = time.mktime(day2)`, I got the error like:

> OverflowError: mktime argument out of range

How can I convert it back to `timestamps`?

Comment: Check out this question, it's quite a fuss: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Converting to string and back is very slow operation. I'd suggest to use that math algorithm anyway:

```
# get integer and fractional parts of modulo division
i, f = divmod(timeStamp, 3600)
# i * 3600 is hour:0:0 time
timestamp1 = i * 3600
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 2):

`strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")` returns a string.
If you want to go down this path, you should call `strptime` to turn it back into a time object:

```
 day1=datetime.datetime.\
    fromtimestamp(float(timeStamp)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")
 day1 = time.strptime(day1, "%Y-%m-%d %H")
 timestamp1 = time.mktime(day1)
```

I would recommend @baldr approach though...

Comment: That has the above error nothing changed. the error : `OverflowError: mktime argument out of range`